# Find the Infinitesimal canonical transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

I am confused by this problem in my homework:

> Given a canonical transformation, where $\alpha>0$,
>   $$q\rightarrow \alpha q,$$
>   $$p\rightarrow \frac{1}{\alpha} p,$$
>   **find the generating function for the corresponding infinitesimal canonical transformation.**

Whats in my mind is, lets define $\epsilon=(\alpha-1)/N$ with $N$ being a huge number, then the transformation can be spanned by the following infinitesimal ones
$$q\rightarrow q+\epsilon q,$$
$$p\rightarrow p-\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}p.$$

However, for this infinitesimal transformation to be canonical we need
$$1=\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
which says 
$$\alpha=1.$$

So this infinitesimal transformation doesn't work? We might need to find fancier forms of the infinitesimal transformations, but I cant think of any anymore...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near the identity $\alpha=1+\epsilon$ and $1/\alpha=1-\epsilon$. The infinitesimal canonical transformations generated by a generator $G(q,p)$ are,
\begin{equation}
q'=q+\epsilon [q,G]_{PB} =q+\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\\
p'=p+\epsilon [p,G]_{PB} =p-\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial q} \ .
\end{equation}
Now $q'=q+\epsilon q$ and $p'=p-\epsilon p$ so that,
\begin{equation}
q+\epsilon q=q+\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\\
p-\epsilon p=p-\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial q} \ .
\end{equation}
The generator is given by the equations,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}=q\\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial q}=p
\end{equation}
which integrate to $G(q,p)=qp$. Now we can write down the infinitesimal canonical transformation again as,
\begin{equation}
q'=q+\epsilon [q,G]_{PB} =q+\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}=q+\epsilon q\\
p'=p+\epsilon [p,G]_{PB} =p-\epsilon\frac{\partial G}{\partial q}=p-\epsilon p \ .
\end{equation}
giving ODEs,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dq}{d\epsilon}=q\\
\frac{dp}{d\epsilon}=-p
\end{equation}
which integrate to $q(\epsilon)=q(0)e^\epsilon$ and $p(\epsilon)=p(0)e^{-\epsilon}$. Now put $\alpha=e^{\epsilon}$ and we get $q'=\alpha q$ and $p'=p/\alpha$ which is the desired finite canonical transformation in the question.